# Clear all values from all text fields when clicking on any of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with :

```
<INPUT  TYPE="text" NAME="name" id="name"  value="Enter your name" size="16">
<INPUT  TYPE="text" NAME="lname" id="lname"  value="Enter your last name" size="16">
```

No matter which field you click on, the values of both should be cleared

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: The point of compatibility view is for making the browser compatible with sites designed for the 1990s. If you are using placeholder, then that isn't the case, so the solution is "Don't turn on compatibility mode when you don't need to".

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/). The default value isn't either.

Comment: Quentin, is not me who turns on or off the compatibility mode, it's the users. So, as a programmer I need to take this into account and show my page correctly in both modes. Don't you agree?

Comment: No. Pandering to a tiny minority of users who turn on a mode to make their browser intentionally buggy is a waste of time.

Comment: tell it to my boss :/

Comment: New approach, no placeholder but need to clear all values

Comment: Instead of abusing the default value to display a label, you could just use a `<label>`.

Comment: Cannot do that, design commands

Comment: Try introducing the design department to the concepts of accessibility and usability (which will benefit a set of users larger than that of "IE 10 users who turn on compatibility mode for sites that it shouldn't be used on").

Comment: You are asking for trouble, use LABELs or find a new job, imho

Comment: Beautiful, but totally unrealistic when the page what due for yesterday

Comment: Wolff: cannot do that, design commands

Comment: Please people, understand that when most of us are asking for help is because we have been trying lots of possibilities before. And most of the time you are our last resource. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<script>
var default_name_value="Enter your name";
var default_lastname_value="Enter your last name";
function empty_fields(){
    $("input[type=text]").each(function(index,item){
       if($(item).val()==default_name_value||$(item).val()==default_lastname_value){
          $(item).val("");
       }
    });
}
</script>

<INPUT  TYPE="text" NAME="name" id="name" onfocus="empty_fields();"  value="Enter your name" size="16">
<INPUT  TYPE="text" NAME="lname" id="lname" onfocus="empty_fields();" value="Enter your last name" size="16">
```

**UPDATE**

this will empty all text boxes in the page 
refine the selector in line 3 to something like `$("#myform input[type=text]")` to empty only boxes in the desired form

**UPDATE 2**

now it will only be emptied for the first time

Comment: So each time someone try to enter something on input, every FORM inputs text are cleared, well, so how can an user enter name & last name??? Seriously OP, you should handle old browsers with label; for modern ones, you can detect them and use placeholder (without label if it is your goal) and maybe some tricks with pseudo elements

Comment: sorry O.O i didn't see that. now i've updated it .. maybe its solved now